# Azure Function Apps - How to Install NPM packages through portal?

Tags: node.js, azure, npm

having a senior moment and hoping one of you can help.

I'm trying to install Axios on a Microsoft Azure Function App that I created in the UI. So, this means it creates two files in my functions directory under site/wwwroot.
[image]

Now the issue i'm having is trying to actually install NPM packages to the the Function. Doing some search on here, I found that you can use Kudu to run NPM commands in the site/wwwroot directory. I have tried that and I believe have successfully done that as seen in the photo below:

[image]

However once I try to run my function through the UI but I receive a 500 Internal Server Error. If I attempt to research the error deeper I get the following error message:

```
Total Count : 4
Message : Result: Failure
Exception: Worker was unable to load function APITrigger: 'Cannot find module 'axios'
Require stack:
- C:\home\site\wwwroot\APITrigger\index.js
- C:\Program Files (x86)\SiteExtensions\Functions\4.22.0\workers\node\dist\src\worker-bundle.js
- C:\Program Files (x86)\SiteExtensions\Functions\4.22.0\workers\node\dist\src\nodejsWorker.js'
Stack: Error: Worker was unable to load function APITrigger: 'Cannot find module 'axios'
Require stack:
- C:\home\site\wwwroot\APITrigger\index.js
- C:\Program Files (x86)\SiteExtensions\Functions\4.22.0\workers\node\dist\src\worker-bundle.js
- C:\Program Files (x86)\SiteExtensions\Functions\4.22.0\workers\node\dist\src\nodejsWorker.js'
at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:995:15)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:841:27)
at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1061:19)
at Object.apply (C:\Program Files (x86)\SiteExtensions\Functions\4.22.0\workers\node\dist\src\worker-bundle.js:2:44135)
at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:103:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\home\site\wwwroot\APITrigger\index.js:1:15)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:14)
at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1213:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1037:32)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:878:12)
```

So, I'm hoping one of you kind people can help me get unstuck! I appreciate any help / guidance!

Answer (score 0):

So figured this out after wasting a few hours on it....it was because I was testing / running the function inside the UI instead of in Postman....once I tested it in Postman it ran perfectly....odd